# How to set an ending point on laxx.js library with the data-translate-x effect

Tags: html, animation

I'm trying to set  scroll effects using the lax library.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="coenter code herentainer-fluid outer">
    <div class="container-fluid inner" style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.17690826330532217) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 94%), url(<?php echo get_field('block_6_background'); ?>) no-repeat;" /> </div>
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-md-12  align-self-center">
            <div class="container lax" data-lax-translate-x="vh 0, -elh (vw*0.4)" data-lax-anchor="self">
                <h1 class="text-white"><?php the_field('title_block_6'); ?></h1>
                <h2 class="text-white"><?php the_field('subtitle_block_6'); ?></h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the scroll effect inside .container .lax end just where the .container .lax itself ends?
Right now the `h1` and `h2` scroll until the end of the container-fluid, and that's not what I want! 
I've been able to set the starting point of the scroll effect modifying the `data-lax-translate-x="vh 0"`, but I can't make it end where I want!

Thanks for your help!
laxx.js --> https://alexfox.dev/laxxx/

Answer (score 0):

You have got a missing <\div>